# Swipe to go back in specific SwiftUI views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app I have set in all my views `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` to have always a custom Back Button, so the iOS classic swipe to go back has been disabled everywhere, but I actually need it only in specific views.

I re enabled it using this code:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

It works but unfortunately it re enables swipe to go back in the entire project, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be managed via some global app state, like

```
class AppState {
  static let shared = AppState()

  var swipeEnabled = false    // << by default
}

extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    // ...

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return AppState.shared.swipeEnabled ? 
                 viewControllers.count > 1 : false // << here !!
    }
}

// ... and somewhere in view, for example
     .onAppear {
        AppState.shared.swipeEnabled = true
     }
     .onDisappear {
        AppState.shared.swipeEnabled = false
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using UINavigationController you can make it another way: Just make default back button in navigation bar invisible. And then "replace" it on your custom button.

I use this way:

1. Set `.tint(.clear)` for `NavigationStack` for make back button "< Back" with no color. Example in my code:

```
    NavigationStack {
        ProfileView()
    }
    .tint(.clear)
    .tabItem {
        Image("profileTabImage")
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        Text("")
    }
    .tag(Tab.profile)
```

2. Set `.navigationTitle("")` for remove "Back" in back button. Now you get only invisible "<" in back button. It also need to set in previous view.
3. Set image in ToolbarItem with offset, so it looks like replace default back button. Example in my code:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Button {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Image("backProfile").offset(x: -35)
            }
        }
    }
}
```